# How to find out if an international transfer will be possible when negotiating a job offer?

Tags: job-offer, new-job, relocation, location

I received a job offer which I'm strongly considering accepting. My biggest concern is that my partner & myself have a dream of living overseas for a few years, and I don't know if this company will allow it. (My current company would allow it.)

It's an international company and they have a handful of employees living in that country, so I imagine this wouldn't be a problem after working there for a few years. However, it's possible that I'd want to switch overseas within less than a year of working at the company.

**Is there a way to find this out before I accept the job offer? I'd seriously reconsider if I knew for sure that they wouldn't allow it, but I don't want to risk the whole offer by asking them outright.**

My question is pretty similar to [this one](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/138868/how-to-find-out-if-work-location-is-flexible-at-potential-company), except that their question was about ad-hoc working from home and mine is about long-term switching. I also read [this question](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/6357/is-it-reasonable-to-ask-to-work-in-a-different-location-than-the-one-i-was-given) but unlike that one, I wouldn't need to switch teams in order to move since my job can be done fully remote (and I'd be working with a bunch of remote people from all over the world, regardless). I also don't need to switch now; this is planning for the near future.

It's also different from [this](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/80869/can-i-ask-to-switch-locations-after-3-months) because the commute wouldn't be my reason for switching.

*NOTE: There are many factors involved with job offers and relationships. For simplicity's sake, please focus your answer on how I can or cannot find out this one piece of information before accepting the offer. I don't need to be told that other factors are more important or I should wait a year or two before trying to move.*

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Is there a way to find this out before I accept the job offer? I'd
>   seriously reconsider if I knew for sure that they wouldn't allow it,
>   but I don't want to risk the whole offer by asking them outright.

If something is important to you, you simply need to ask about it.

Something like "My partner and I have a dream of living overseas for a few years. Is transferring to X something that would be allowed here somewhere down the road?" should get your answer. If the answer is a positive one, you may or may not want to follow up with something about "within a year" if your time frame is set.

It's okay to jeopardize a potential offer for important aspects of the job. Offers that don't contain the possibility for something that you consider important enough are not ones you should accept anyway.